# Regular expression to find all the string that does not contains _(Underscore) and :(Colon) in PySpark Dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a column in data frame named as  **"tags"**. I need to extract the values based on the condition. The condition is it should not contains  _(Underscore) and :(Colon).

**For example:**

"tags": "hai, hello, amount_10, amount_90, total:100"

**Expected result:**

"new_column" : "hai, hello"

**For your information:**

I extracted all the amount tags by

```
collectAmount = udf(lambda s: list(map(lambda amount: amount.split('_')[1] if len(collection) > 0
                        else amount, re.findall(r'(amount_\w+)', s))), ArrayType(StringType()))

productsDF = productsDF.withColumn('amount_tag', collectAmount('tags'))
```

Comment: Should we split by `,` to separate the words first?

Comment: What is the type of the tags column? Can you please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples)?

Comment: Yes, @Ankur. You are correct.....

Comment: Tags is in the type of String.... @cronoik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
df.withColumn('new_column',expr('''concat_ws(',',array_remove(transform(split(tags,','), x -> regexp_extract(x,'^(?!.*_)(?!.*:).+$',0)),''))''')).show(2,False)

+-------------------------------------------+----------+
|tags                                       |new_column|
+-------------------------------------------+----------+
|hai, hello, amount_10, amount_90, total:100|hai, hello|
|hai, hello, amount_10, amount_90, total:100|hai, hello|
+-------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Perfect...! @Shubham Jain

Comment: Use a simpler regex, `regexp_extract(x,'^[^_:]+$',0)`

Answer (score 3):

No regex needed really:

```
tags = ["hai", "hello", "amount_10", "amount_90", "total:100"]

new_column = [tag for tag in tags if not any(junk in tag for junk in ["_", ":"])]
print(new_column)
```

If you insist on using regular expressions:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r'^(?!.*_)(?!.*:).+$')
new_column = [tag for tag in tags if rx.match(tag)]
print(new_column)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/GnpWfb/1/).

Comment: Hello @Jan. It's not a normal list in python. It's pyspark data frame.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex as per the answer above, but you will need to either wrap it in a `udf` or as I show below, use the `pyspark` built-ins:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df= df.withColumn("extracted", F.regexp_extract("tags","[_:]", 0))
df.filter(df["extracted"] == '').select("tags").show()
```

Comment: It's not giving exact result @ags29.

Comment: +----------+
|plain_tags|
+----------+
|         :|
|         _|
|         _|
|         _|
I 'm getting this alone

Comment: yes, please. if you can provide a sample then I will amend my answer.